# Need the selected index for select that contains optgroup

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="test1">
    <optgroup label="group1">Group 1
        <option value="one">Option 1 of Group 1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="group2">Group 2
        <option value="one">Option 1 of Group 2</option>
        <option value="two">Option 2 of Group 2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Option values can be duplicates so I'd like to get the index. But when I try

```
$('#test1 option:selected').index();
```

It shows index relative to group. Is there an easy way to show it based all groups.

```
$('#test1')[0].length //equals 3 and this is what I'd like the index based off
```

Currently, if I pick `'Option 2 Group 2'` it shows an index of 1, relative to Group 2. I'd like it to show index = 2, based off entire list.

http://jsfiddle.net/waeeq2xd/1/

Comment: why is it that I have to use '[0]' in the following $('#test')[0].length to get the length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use the `.index()` function like:

```
$('#test1 option').index($('#test1 option:selected'))
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wm1ocr9k/1)**

As the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/) state:

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
> jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
> position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

You actually had an error when you said "It shows index relative to group". Without an argument passed to index(), it gives you the index relative to its sibling elements.

Comment: You probably want to use `#test1` in your first selector of you'll check the index within all options of all selects on the page.

Answer (score 4):

You are mistaken. Index starts from 0 where else the length is a count which will return 3.

You could use `this.selectedIndex` instead of all that jQuery which should return the right index based off the drop down.

http://jsfiddle.net/59xpn9mm/